# unit-test for c - how to test a 'unit' without recompiling/relinking?

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing

I'm new to unit-testing, but not C (in an embedded environment) - I have a conceptual problem that I'm sure has a simple answer... I'm just having trouble getting that answer.

I've started to experiment with unit-testing, after reading a couple of books on the subject - the examples in the book always seem clear, but trivial, but neither really touched on the piece I'm missing (or if it did, it went over my head).

I've started to experiment with unit testing on one of our protocol stacks that has four layers (app, presentation, session, transport). Keeping the example simple for clarity, each layer might have one to several functions. If I want to unit test the App layer, I think I'm to understand that I'd 'stub' out the interface to the presentation layer (or create a mock for the presentation layer?), in order to isolate the application layer. I've tried this out, and all seems good.

However, my question is then, how do you unit test the presentation layer without recompiling or relinking the target and thereby generating a bunch of executables?

Thanks for insight.

Comment: What are the public interfaces to your layers? Can you exercise the API from a separate executable>

Comment: Some unit test library required you to build with some custom flags in order to mock out global functions. Why you want to avoid rebuild? It should be fast anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure of C++ but in case of C,
a suggested method is to have conditional compilation. So that you can compile either as real project or for unit testing. So in unit testing the stubs are executed.

But since you want not to recompile it, there is very rude method and that is to have 2 parts for your function which depends on a flag. So on run time if you change the flag value, the second part is executed so your real functions can act as a stub in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, I work at Typemock.

You can use [Typemock Isolator++](http://www.typemock.com/isolatorpp-product-page) to mock out anything you need in c\c++.
Isolator works in runtime, so you will not need to recompile nor change your production code, [see example](http://www.typemock.com/docs?book=Ipp&page=Documentation%2Ffaking_abstract_classes.htm):

production.cpp in production.dll

```
class MyPureClass
{
public:
   virtual int GetResult() = 0;
}
```

test.cpp in test.dll

```
TEST_METHOD(Method1)
{   
    //mock the class = its methods will return fake objects (recursively) or default values
    MyPureClass* fakeMyClass = FAKE<MyPureClass>(); 

    //assign specific return value to a method
    WHEN_CALLED(fakeMyClass->GetResult()).Return(10);
}
```

You can also mock concrete classes, static and global functions... in the same manner.